# Drupal views random list with different css for result 1

Tags: random, view, drupal-7

I want to create a random list of pictures with views 3 in Drupal 7 where the first picture ist larger than the other ones.

So each time I reload I have a random list and always the first result is much bigger.

How do i do this?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate place for this question, this is a site for programming related programs not UI configuration questions. You'll probably get a much better response over at drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Views node split](http://drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) which does exactly what you want.